# module name is shadowing global name used in binding

Tags: javascript, binding, ffi, reason, bucklescript

**tl;dr:** How to change the following binding to be able to write `Intl.DateTimeFormat.make()` instead of `Intl_.DateTimeFormat.make()`?

```ml
type dateTimeFormat;

[@bs.deriving abstract]
type formatOptions = {
  [@bs.optional]
  weekday: string,
  [@bs.optional]
  day: string,
  [@bs.optional]
  month: string,
};

module Intl_ {
    module DateTimeFormat {
      module Impl {
        type t;
      };

      [@bs.new] external make: unit => Impl.t = "Intl.DateTimeFormat";
      [@bs.send] external format: (Impl.t, Js.Date.t) => string = "";
    };
}

Intl_.DateTimeFormat.make()
  ->Intl_.DateTimeFormat.format(Js.Date.make())
  ->Js.log;
```

**The issue**

Without the underscore, this would compile to:

```
var Impl = /* module */[];

var DateTimeFormat = /* module */[/* Impl */Impl];

var Intl = /* module */[/* DateTimeFormat */DateTimeFormat];

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(new Date()));

exports.Intl = Intl;
```

The issue is that `var Intl = ...` shadows the global `Intl`, and thus breaks `new Intl.DateTimeFormat()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd consider this a bug in BuckleScript. This problem was most recently brought up in [issue #3268](https://github.com/BuckleScript/bucklescript/issues/3268) and partially resolved in [this commit](https://github.com/BuckleScript/bucklescript/commit/506ac5500d4f9af982983be6309733787d8a5196), but it still leaves a lot of names unreserved. You should consider bringing this up there or in a new issue.

In the meantime, you can work around this by fully qualifying the name. `Intl` isn't actually a global object, but attached to *the* global object, which in the context of a web page is `window`. But since JavaScript will look for names on the global object when it's not found in the local environment, it looks very much like a global name.

So if you change `make` to:

```
[@bs.new] external make: unit => Impl.t = "window.Intl.DateTimeFormat";
```

it should work fine.

Comment: This won't be an issue soon. On `bs-platform@next` it's already resolved (as per comments in the issue you linked to).

Comment: confirmed that it works without the underscore in bucklescript v7.2.2